# React router v5 not working with nested routes on production only

Tags: reactjs, webpack, react-router

I converted **HashRouter** to **BrowserRouter** recently as it works fine on dev environment as I added

```
  devServer: {
    historyApiFallback: true,
    allowedHosts: 'all',
  },
```

to webpack.dev.config

When I run the app on prod, myapp.com works but **myapp.com/home** won't work (it renders nginx 404 error).

If I go to **myapp.com/#/home** then it will redirect me to **myapp.com/home** and page will render (I have catch all logic to convert legacy hash into normal urls).

Here is my complete webpack config.

webpack.common.js

```
module.exports = {
  entry: path.join(__dirname, 'src', 'index.js'),
  output: {
    path: path.resolve(__dirname, 'dist'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    chunkFilename: '[id].js',
    publicPath: '/',
    hashFunction: 'xxhash64',
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['.js', '.jsx'],
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.(scss)$/,
        use: [
          {
            // inject CSS to page
            loader: 'style-loader',
          },
          {
            // translates CSS into CommonJS modules
            loader: 'css-loader',
          },
          {
            // Run postcss actions
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              // `postcssOptions` is needed for postcss 8.x;
              // if you use postcss 7.x skip the key
              postcssOptions: {
                // postcss plugins, can be exported to postcss.config.js
                plugins: function () {
                  return [require('autoprefixer')]
                },
              },
            },
          },
          {
            // compiles Sass to CSS
            loader: 'sass-loader',
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: {
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: ['@babel/preset-env', '@babel/preset-react'],
          },
        },
      },
      {
        test: /\.css$/,
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        use: [
          { loader: 'style-loader' },
          {
            loader: 'css-loader',
            options: {
              modules: {
                localIdentName: '[name]__[local]___[hash:base64:5]',
              },
              sourceMap: true,
            },
          },
          {
            loader: 'postcss-loader',
            options: {
              postcssOptions: {
                plugins: [['autoprefixer', {}]],
              },
            },
          },
        ],
      },
      {
        test: /\.(png|jpe?g|gif|svg)$/,
        use: [
          {
            loader: 'url-loader',
            options: { limit: 10000, name: 'static/media/[name].[hash:8].[ext]' },
          },
        ],
      },
    ],
  },
  plugins: [
    new HtmlWebpackPlugin({
      template: __dirname + '/public/index.html',
      filename: 'index.html',
      inject: 'body',
      favicon: './public/favicon.ico',
      manifest: './public/manifest.json',
    }),
  ],
}
```

webpack.prod.js

```
module.exports = merge(common, {
  mode: 'production',
  performance: {
    hints: false,
    maxEntrypointSize: 512000,
    maxAssetSize: 512000,
  },
  plugins: [
    new Dotenv({
      path: './.env',
    }),
  ],
})
```

What am I missing?

### Edit

**myapp.com** works but if I want to navigate to **myapp.com/intro**, it will give me ngnix 404.

Comment: I got it working but not sure if this is what I want.. what I did:
made default.conf for nginx config override,
In dockerfile, COPY default.conf /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf to override default conf.
it seems to be working... for now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because, your routes are internal to your website and the server(Nginx) won't be aware of what file to deliver for those internal routes.

Your server knows for url "myapp.com" it has to deliver "index.html", but don't know what file to deliver incase of other url like "myapp.com/home" so it returns "404.html" which is default nginx config.

These routes are required to explicitly mentioned in your deployment config. Like, you have to update nginx config to deliver "index.html" for all url starts with "myapp.com"

It worked in HashRouter because server won't parse url after "#", so for server `myapp.com/#/home` and `myapp.com/#/` are same. Server delivers the `index.html` then your HashRouter parse the url after '#' and delivers content accordingly

Comment: makes perfect sense! code knows how to redirect but nginx doesn't! so configuring nginx seems to be valid! Do you think there was a way to fix this with webpack?

Comment: As far as I know, we can't fix this in webpack, as this issue is happening because server don't know what file to deliver.